# how to use a variable in a where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, jsp

I use jsp and sql and I want to query a table using a variable  that I have already declared (entity)
here is my query:

```
..
String **entite**="informatique";
entite="informatique"

...
rs = st.executeQuery ("select * from User where User.id_e= &**entite** ");
```

**entite is a variable**

my question is: how to use a variable in a where clause

Comment: JSP and SQL. Please read about SQL injection before proceeding!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My prefered solution - Use a `PreparedStatement` with `?` and `setString(...)` for parameters.

See further details here:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: -1 for suggesting to inline a (potential) HTTP parameter directly in SQL in a JSP page... I'll post my little `' 1; drop database` entite to your page (in case this is not clear, please read about SQL injection)

Answer (score 0):

The best and safe way is to use PreparedStatement to bind variables to the query.

For example see (hope the link does not break in a second)
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html

You can use escaping techniques, however they are error prone and quite too often lead to SQL injection attacks and/or database corruption.